# When should a team name be capitalized?

Tags: nouns, capitalization

> Jhon is a part the Huston Racing Club, and he is on the **electrical team**.

or

> Jhon is a part the Huston Racing Club, and he is on the **Electrical Team**.

I find this confusing because it's a team within a team. Is "electrical team" just considered a common noun? I think it shouldn't be capitalized but I don't know.

Comment: If it has a name, capitalize the name. If it is just a generic term, don't. For example: "The wrecking crew will tear down the building tomorrow" and "The Wrecking Crew, a top-ranked trivia team, will play the Beer Guzzlers tomorrow night at Barney's Lounge, where there will be plenty of beer guzzlers not involved in the contest."

Answer (score 5):

Things get capitalised when they are *proper nouns* (or *proper names*). Now, when something clears that bar is a local concern for an organisation. The general concept of an *executive committee* for a club or society would not require it to be capitalised, but within a given club they might choose to refer to their executive committee as the Executive Committee. A department of a large organisation might be capitalised within the organisation, but the idea of a science department isn't. Or the organisation might not treat department names as proper nouns.

A team within a team might be capitalised, that's up to the organisation involved. they might even capitalise the designation of the team-within-a-team without the word *team*, maing it "he is on the Electrical team". I would say the default is **not to capitalise** such things, because it is **simply a description** - the team that deals with the electrics.  However, depending on organisational preferences, such units *might* be capitalised.